# multiple noUiSlider instantiations issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nouislider

I'm trying to create multiple noUiSliders in one page, but I'm getting this error "noUiSlider.create requires a single element".

Basically, I'm instantiating two (or more) sliders (with different class) from different functions but I'm getting the above errors.

Anyone with some experience with this plugin?

Here is an example:

```
var Slider1Handler = function(){

 var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider1');
 noUiSlider.create(slider1, {
      start: [ 0 ],
      connect: [true, false],
      step: 1000,
      tooltips: true,
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: {
        'min': [  2000 ],
        'max': [ 10000 ]
      }
 });
 };

var Slider2Handler = function(){

 var slider2 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider2');
 noUiSlider.create(slider2, {
      start: [ 0 ],
      connect: [true, false],
      step: 1000,
      tooltips: true,
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: {
        'min': [  2000 ],
        'max': [ 10000 ]
      }
 });
 };
```

Comment: Just a guess, but since getElementsByClassName returns a collection even if there is only one elment by that class, try `document.getElementsByClassName('slider1')[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList`, not a single element. You can use any of the following options:

- Add an `id` to the elements and use `getElementById`;
- Take the first element in the `nodeList`: document.getElementsByClassName('slider2')[0];
- Use `document.querySelector('.slider2')`, which *will* return a single element;

Comment: Thanks really appreciate!

Comment: Do you know how to show string instead of decimal in the labels? It seems it shows only numbers and I'm going a bit crazy to find a solution :/

Comment: You can use the [`format`](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-formatting) option.